# MPAndroid chart in ConstraintLayout with additional widgets (they are not visible)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, mpandroidchart

I am trying to add PieChart from MPAndroidChart and seekBar under it.

But still no luck, chart is visible, but other content is noT visible, despite it visible when I open design tab during xml configuration.

I already have tried to set a barrier and with groups with weights but still.

Could please anyone give any advice how to properly align chart to be able to see other widgets on view.

Here is my xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/pieChart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Problem]

**ANSWER**

The first and correct version of answer from Ashish Kudale is: Use LinearLayout with weight:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chartContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/pieChart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LinearLayout Insted of ConstraintLayout.

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/pieChart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What it does is places all items in the screen and remaining place is occupied by item which has `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yeah it's right. But could you please give me an advice how to place additional text view to the right of seek bar. Is it possible ?

Comment: I am updating ans

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I know it's not under this topic. But it would be really awesome if you help me with that)

Comment: seems like your updated answer in not working, unfortunately.

Comment: I have decided to put textView under the chart and above the seekBar.

Comment: OK. You will try your own or should I help?

Comment: Thanks for care) I will do it on my own)

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, still if you need help comment down here.